# Photography from geostationary orbit

Tags: lens, selection

Satellites are at 38000 km from earth. What practical lens will allow me to resolve 1 km (5.43 arc-sec) and the earth subtends roughly 20 degrees at the camera.

Comment: Nothing that is "practical" will do what you want. Such lenses are highly "impractical" to obtain and place in orbit.

Comment: On such distance are geostationary satellites, not all satellites. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit

Comment: Is this a theoretical question, or are you actually building such a satellite?

Comment: Please clarify: when you say "practical lens", are you asking about off-the-shelf camera lenses (such as Canon or Nikon), or are you asking about industrial or scientific lenses that are designed to withstand the stresses of launch/deployment and can operate in the extreme environment of space?

Comment: Is this a problem from your math homework?

Comment: Do you mention the angle subtended by the Earth because you want to include the whole globe in the field of view? If so, you should start by asking questions about sensors (or maybe full systems) rather than about lenses, because you need about 175Mpix in a square format, which is somewhat above what's currently available off-the-shelf.

Answer (score 2):

5.43 arcsec ≈ 0.0015°.

On a full frame DSLR, a 300mm lens gives you 6.87° field of view.

6.87°/0.0015° = 4580, which is a less than the horizontal width in pixels of many full frame sensors.

We're obviously not taking the curvature of the earth into account here, but in the center of the image at least, a 300mm lens on a full frame DSLR should let you resolve better than 1km (assuming your 5.43arcsec figure is correct), at least in the center of the image.

Comment: If the sensor has a Bayer mask, then you must also take that into account. The maximum resolution of such a camera will be the width of two pixels, not the width of a single pixel. You're also ignoring the part of the question that states the camera is not perpendicular to the ground, but is pointed from a 20° angle. Although not clear, the question *seems* to also want the photo to contain the full disc of the earth.

Comment: @MichaelClark, the question doesn't say that the camera is pointed at a 20° angle: it says that a 20° field of view would be needed (in the narrow dimension) to cover the full disc.

Comment: @ Peter Yeah, OK. It didn't seem that clear when I read it earlier. On a FF camera a 300mm lens only has an AoV of about 4.5° in the short dimension. The *diagonal* AoV is only a little over 8°. That's nowhere near the needed 20° mentioned in the OP. The solution to this problem is obviously a very large resolution camera with an equally high resolution lens, probably in a format much larger than 36x24mm.

Comment: @MichaelClark The question doesn't say anything about including the entire Earth in one image, so you're simply adding an assumption that I didn't. There's so little information in the question that all we can really do is the kind of back-of-the-envelope calculation I've shown above.

Comment: @Caleb The question seems to me to ask what lens will allow to resolve 1km **and** the Earth subtends approximately 20° at the camera. Why would the second clause be included if the intent was not to indicate a desire to include that 20° in the field of view?

Comment: @MichaelClark The Earth will be the same apparent size from a distance of 38,000km no matter what lens you choose; I took the 20° as extra info to help with the calculation. In any case, I completely agree that capturing a field of view > 20° **and** providing 0.0015° resolution will require a different lens and an unusually large sensor. Unfortunately, the OP hasn't offered any clarification as to the actual needs.

Answer (score 0):

This question is above my pay grade. That being said, I will take a stab at it. I know that the unaided human eye is able to resolve objects from a distance of 3000 times their span. Thus a 1 kilometer plot of ground will be resolved by a person with normal vision from a distance of 3000 kilometers.

Now we are taking a geocentric orbit, that’s an altitude of 35,786 kilometers. From that altitude the human eye can resolve a 12 kilometer plot of land. Now if we apply 12X magnification, via binoculars or telephoto lens, we can just resolve 1 kilometer, we will see a point with no detail. Therefor I think we need to apply 25X magnification to do this deed.

The astronomical community has long supposed that  a 50mm focal length delivers 1X magnification. That being the case, we mount a 50 X 25 = 1,250mm lens on a 35mm camera for this task.

Sorry to report that the angle of view will be only 0.2° so including the moon in this shot is out the window.  Also, know that I am overflowing with gobbledygook meaning I have been wrong more than 35,786 times.